# Apache redirect if no parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried searching for this solution and apologize ahead of time if it was out there and I missed it.

I am working on setting up 301 redirects on an apache server to point old pages on a CMS to new pages.  During the transition, we need to operate pages on both systems.  They have a page that:

- if has no GET parameters tacked on the end, should redirect to the new CMS
- if it has GET parameters, it should NOT be redirected and should continue working with the old CMS

I have seen many mod_rewrite rules to do the opposite of what I am looking for, but not one that will only activate if there are no GET parameters.  I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page.php$<br />
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^<br />
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://new.domain.com [L,R=301]
```

If someone goes to old.domain.com/page.php they should be redirected to new.domain.com.  If someone goes to old.domain.com/page.php?var=1&var=2, they should remain on this domain and not be redirected.

Thanks, in advance, for any help you could provide,

Dave